# Automatic calculate Recall/ Precision to Word2vec model

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, synonym

i am doing synonym-detection based on word2vec models with gensim. What possibilities are for automatic calculate of recall and precision. I just want some metrics based on the trained Model whitout giving a list of correct synoynms.
Cheers

Comment: You'll need to supply some set of correct/desired/relevant answers to have any hope of calculated a 'recall' or 'precision' evaluation, as they're defined in terms of relevant-vs-irrelevant instances.

Comment: Is there a machine learning library where i can send a list of synonyms and the model and get metrics like Recall and precison back?

Comment: I don't know any library offering that, but also, the idea of "getting recall & precision from a list of synonyms" seems like a nonsensical qeury to me, so I may not understand your goal. Can you be more specific, with examples of the exact input you'd provide, and what yardstick it'd be judging that input against, and why you'd be using 'machine learning' rather than some reference lexicon to known-synonyms (like a thesaurus)?